# Allow people to connect to my https website using http connection?

Tags: http, https, apache2

My website is currently https. But when attempting to browse it on a new computer, it always shows ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED unless I turn it from http://mywebsite.com to https://mywebsite.com and then it's fine after that since it's saved to the browser.

How can I allow http connection to https website? I tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}  !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

But it's still the same.

Server: Apache2

Answer (score 0):

on certbot, allow redirects so it will do the ReWrite code for you.